# Issue in table rows cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have an issue in my [table rows cloned](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/cpRa2/3/). For example once I edit both the columns of my row cloned and then I click on my add button I get the row cloned already edited as previously and not with my *placeholder "Click to edit"* as in this other [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LAECx/)

What function is missing in my Table to make the rows cloned with my placeholders and not edited?

Comment: i don't understand your question. is that repeated 'Add' button your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone the row with the same value entered in the text boxes just comment this line in click event

```
 //$clone.find(':text').val('');
```

because it clear all textboxes

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAECx/226/)

Comment: i think you meant the opposite by the way...when i add the row cloned i dont want any value inside

Comment: OK, I got it but when you clone the row it doesn't contain any textbox it just contain the `<p>` tag, so you clone it with its text

Comment: I make an example,  i edit the row then i clone it clicking the add button, when i get the new row cloned i want it blank just like the original with the placeholder "Click to edit" and not with the values i have inserted. If you edit the row and then you clone it you get the rows edited. its clearer?

Comment: you can make a template fro your row instead of cloning the previous one. [this](http://jsfiddle.net/S3kZw/) is an example of what i mean. note I didn't handle editing event, you already have implemented it

Comment: Thanks Amir, i am really close to achieve it, now the only problem is that i need to configure the the Input button to remove the row cloned see it here http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/S3kZw/3/, any idea? :D

Comment: the problem was calling the function which add new row when you click on remove button. I edited your code and the problem is fixed, try it now http://jsfiddle.net/S3kZw/12/